# scaling a stroke mask in after effects?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have an imported illustrator image that I'm trying to create a stroke mask over so I can animate it's reveal (like someone writing it). Unfortunately, when I try to use the pen tool on the layer it keeps changing the cursor to the "add point" which then makes the next click a brand new path. It's basically impossible to make any kind of path this way.

So, I made an adjustment layer and drew the mask on top of that. But when I copy and paste the mask onto the illustrator layer it's scaled waaaay up. I can't find a way to scale the mask down. When I click on the mask it doesn't give me the box around it, only the actual stroke points (which just move that one point).

Is there not a way to scale a path?

Answer (score 1):

To scale a mask as if you were using the group select tool in Illustrator either alt-click the mask, or hit <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.  It's truly perplexing how all the Adobe apps have different tools and shortcuts for the same tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just create an animated writing effect, I use this script:
http://aescripts.com/quickdraw/

It works better for complex shapes than the [built in write-on effect](https://library.creativecow.net/articles/devis_andrew/AE-Basics-30-The-Write-On-Effect/video-tutorial) in AE.

Alternatively, this script allows you to scale paths: 
http://aescripts.com/shapes-and-masks/

Have a look at the video from about 4m30s in:
https://youtu.be/3SSsgdeMSmw?t=4m31s

But I think what you need is the first one from the sounds of it...